# locale is not saving in getstorage

Tags: flutter-getx

i want to save the locale to getstorage,but not storing and freeze  the app when i call the saveLocaleMethod.I am using getstorage to store the locale.It does not give any log on console though i have use try,catch to handle any error.
my code to handle the locale:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

class HandleLocale {
  final _storage = GetStorage();
  final key = 'locale';

  void saveLocale(Locale locale) {
    try {
      _storage.write(key, locale);
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  bool isSavedLocale() {
    return _storage.read(key) != null;
  }

  Locale getLocale() {
    print("locale${isSavedLocale()}");
    return isSavedLocale()
        ? const Locale('np', 'NPL')
        : const Locale('en', 'US');
  }

  void changeLocale(Locale locale) {
    try {
      print(locale);

      saveLocale(locale);
      Get.updateLocale(locale);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving locale: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

and my locale is:

```
 final List locale = [
        {"name": "English", "locale": const Locale('en', 'US')},
        {"name": "नेपाली", "locale": const Locale('np', 'NPL')},
        {"name": "हिंदी", "locale": const Locale('hi', 'IN')}
      ];

ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        Get.back();
                        HandleLocale().changeLocale(locale[index]['locale']);
                        // changeLanguage();
                      },
                      title: SmallText(text: locale[index]['name']),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: ((context, index) {
                    return const Divider(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    );
                  }),
                  itemCount: locale.length),
```

Comment: i have solved by doing norhing